# Accessing App Store Data

Tags: app-store, itunes-store

Is there a way to access app logo, category, price and other app store information using the app store url.

Want my app to be able to access app store information from the apps url. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But you need to be more specific with your question.

Comment: I have a url to a app store app, like say clash of clans. How do I then access information like category: game, price: free and the logo image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the iTunes Search API: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

This page can help you better understand how the iTunes Search API works: http://www.phponwebsites.com/2015/03/get-app-details-from-apple-itunes-using-php.html